# PHP file_get_contents - Don't know how to select a specific class/div

Tags: php

I'm trying to show the €(number) https://www.stratisrate.com/ on my site but i dont know how to show it alone and making it into a variable instead of showing the whole thing. I have this code right now

```
<?php 

        $content = file_get_contents("https://www.stratisrate.com/");

        echo $content;

    ?>
```

But i dont know how to only show the number (I have looked at a couple tutorials but i still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Read about DomDocument and parsing html

Comment: this article may helps you.. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/html-xpath-query/

Comment: @splash58 already tried that but still cannot figure it out

Comment: Show us your code, we'll try to find errors in it

Comment: @splash58 it is not an error i just dont know how to do it. here you can see what i mean: http://fluffyme.xyz/code/workspace/Stratis/index.php the page has a lot of stuff in it but the only number i want to show is the €and the numbers behind it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse the DOM as suggested in the comments, or you could make use of the JSON response that is used to refresh the content via AJAX.

Try this:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.stratisrate.com/json/load/rate.json'), true);

// this will print the whole array under the key 'euro'
print_r($result['euro']);

//This will get you just the value you asked for
print_r($result['euro']['rate']);
```

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "euro": {
         "rate_title": "euro",
         "rate": "3.37428419",
         "strat": 0.296359,
         "symbol": "&euro;"
    },
    "dollar": {
         "rate_title": "dollar",
         "rate": "3.33987",
         "strat": 0.299413,
         "symbol": "&#36;"
    },
    "bitcoin": {
         "rate_title": "bitcoin",
         "rate": "0.00163",
         "strat": 613.496933,
         "symbol": "Ƀ"
   }
}
```

I found this by looking at the XHR requests under the Network tab in google chrome dev tools. 
[image: Ajax request to update content]

Then I simply check open the url for that XHR call and got the results (no auth token or login required)

Comment: Well this is a diffrent thing than i tried but it worked so thanks

Comment: nice solution +1, for your search :)

Comment: @FluffyMe - You should do this instead of scraping the HTML for sure, if it has the data you need.

Comment: I was coming back to post it as an answer. Squirreled!